# how to create stars when I implement android smart banner

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I am using https://github.com/jasny/jquery.smartbanner/blob/master/jquery.smartbanner.js to implement a smart banner on my website, want to mimic the style of jet.com, everything is good except the stars below the “Jet for android", Anyone has the experience how to develop the stars?[jet.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8G32.png)
Thanks for your help.

Comment: &#9733; &#9734; `code: &#9733; &#9734;` You can use it in any HTML element. Do you want to accept this? Let me know.

Comment: A good demo: `★☆☆☆☆`

Comment: I would recommend using [native app banner](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/increasing-engagement-with-app-install-banners-in-chrome-for-android) instead - Way better user experience! Also look at: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html